# How can I convert String into TextField, javaFX. from the child class

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans, scenebuilder

I would like to create an object for the Faculty class(child class of FacultyApp), where I can input some values

error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to TextField
Faculty faculty = new Faculty(" ", " ", " ");

```
FXMLDocumentController
```

public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

```
private Label label;
@FXML
private TextField employeeName;
@FXML
private TextField employeeTitle;
@FXML
private TextField emailAddress;
@FXML
private Button SaveButton;




@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO
}    
public void setNAME(TextField employeeName) {
     employeeName.getText();    
}
public void setADDRESS(TextField emailAddress) {
    emailAddress.getText();
}
public void setTITLE(TextField employeeTitle) {

employeeTitle.getText();
}

@FXML
private void saveInfo(ActionEvent event) {
    Faculty faculty = new Faculty(" ", " ", " ");
    String textField = new TextField().toString();
    faculty.setNAME(employeeName);
    faculty.setADDRESS(emailAddress);
    faculty.setTITLE(employeeTitle);
    
    String message = "YOUR INPUT HAS BEEN SAVED";
    Alert a = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION); 
    a.setContentText(message +"\nEmployee Name: "+employeeName +"\nEmployee Title: "+ employeeTitle +"\nEmail Address: " + emailAddress);
    a.show();  
    
}
```

}

```
childClass from MainClass
```

public class Faculty extends FacultyApp{
private TextField title, name, address;

```
public Faculty (TextField employeeName, TextField emailAddress, TextField employeeTitle){
    title = employeeTitle;
    name = employeeName;
    address = emailAddress;
}

public void setNAME(TextField employeeName) {
    name = employeeName;
}
public TextField  getNAME(){
    return name;
}
public void setADDRESS(TextField emailAddress) {
    address = emailAddress;
}
public TextField getADDRESS(){
    return address;
}

public void setTITLE(TextField employeeTitle) {
    title = employeeTitle;
}
public TextField getTITLE(){
    return title;
}
```

}

Comment: a) don't pass around nodes (for data), instead model the data such that it is unaware of where/how it might be visualized b) java naming conventions, please c) take the time to format your code! d) work through a tutorial on java language basice .. (something like new TextField().toString is utter .. [censored] - what do you expect to happen?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Faculty` Class' constructor expects 3 arguments of type `TextField`, but you're trying to pass 3 `String` Objects.

Since you're using setters, why don't you remove the current constructor and create a new `Faculty` Object by using the default constructor?

So remove this from the `Faculty` class:

```
public Faculty (TextField employeeName, TextField emailAddress, TextField employeeTitle){
    title = employeeTitle;
    name = employeeName;
    address = emailAddress;
}
```

And in `FXMLDocumentController` change

```
Faculty faculty = new Faculty(" ", " ", " ");
```

into

```
Faculty faculty = new Faculty();
```